# Can Auction be played on a deed that is already Private?

Tags: doomtown-reloaded

The Action card [Auction](http://dtdb.co/en/card/01111) says the following:

> **Noon:** Choose a deed in play. It becomes Private. If you own and control that deed, gain 1 ghost rock for each dude controlled by another player at that deed.

Is it possible to play this card on a deed that is already Private? Or is it only playable on a deed that is initially Public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an in depth discussion of costs vs. requirements by the rule team [here](http://www.alderac.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=375&t=113319). It boils down to this: the first sentence after the bold text & colon is a cost and must be paid in order to use the card. Everything after that you try to execute, but if you are not able to do so just continue on.

So for Auction, the cost is simply "Choose a deed in play." The only restriction in that sentence is "in play", so already Private deeds are fine. The rest of the text then executes. "It becomes Private" has no effect, but the text about gaining ghost rock executes as normal.